# Android exception handling

Tags: android, url, inputstream, httpurlconnection, ioexception

> 1. The Code below on execution in android throws IOException but not wen executed as a java project.
> 2. Also i am unable to view the exception in the console that has occurred if i use e.printstacktrace.
>
> > Kindly reply as soon as possible

```
public String convert(String from, String to,int amt){
    String result= null;
    URL url = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://www.exchangerate-api.com/"+from+"/"+to+"/"+amt+"?k=ZTKOy-28yPI-g2cQd");
        System.out.println("hai");
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        result = readStream(in);
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
public static String readStream(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in),1000);
    for (String line = r.readLine(); line != null; line =r.readLine()){
        sb.append(line);
    }
    in.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

---

```
08-17 12:30:31.356: WARN/System.err(946): java.net.UnknownHostException: www.exchangerate-api.com
08-17 12:30:31.416: WARN/System.err(946):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:506)
08-17 12:30:31.447: WARN/System.err(946):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:294)
08-17 12:30:31.468: WARN/System.err(946):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
08-17 12:30:31.496: WARN/System.err(946):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:68)
08-17 12:30:31.517: WARN/System.err(946):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:48)
08-17 12:30:31.537: WARN/System.err(946):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:298)
08-17 12:30:31.557: WARN/System.err(946):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:89)
08-17 12:30:31.586: WARN/System.err(946):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHttpConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:285)
08-17 12:30:31.606: WARN/System.err(946):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.makeConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:267)
08-17 12:30:31.626: WARN/System.err(946):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1018)
08-17 12:30:31.649: WARN/System.err(946):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:510)
08-17 12:30:31.679: WARN/System.err(946):     at com.CurrencyConverterActivity.ConverterCurrency.convert(ConverterCurrency.java:110)
08-17 12:30:31.697: WARN/System.err(946):     at com.CurrencyConverterActivity.ConverterCurrency.onClick(ConverterCurrency.java:67)
08-17 12:30:31.716: WARN/System.err(946):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
08-17 12:30:31.736: WARN/System.err(946):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
08-17 12:30:31.746: WARN/System.err(946):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-17 12:30:31.766: WARN/System.err(946):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-17 12:30:31.786: WARN/System.err(946):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-17 12:30:31.806: WARN/System.err(946):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
08-17 12:30:31.826: WARN/System.err(946):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-17 12:30:31.836: WARN/System.err(946):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-17 12:30:31.856: WARN/System.err(946):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-17 12:30:31.876: WARN/System.err(946):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-17 12:30:31.896: WARN/System.err(946):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

> this the exception that occurs..

Comment: kindly check in the logcat not into the console from ddms

Comment: Have you provided with proper permissions?

Comment: Have you tried using sysout(e.toString());

Comment: It's most likely a problem with the internet connection on the Android device. Try accessing http://www.exchangerate-api.com/ in the Android browser to verify that it's possible to reach the server from the device at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

provide Internet permssion

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>. In android-manifest
```

And if you provided already then post your log cat

**Try that below code**

```
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(newUrl).openConnection(); 
            con.setRequestMethod("POST"); 
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", ""+Integer.toString(newUrl.getBytes().length)); 
            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US"); 
            con.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close"); 
            con.setUseCaches (false); 
            con.setDoOutput(true); 
            con.setDoInput(true); 
            InputStream in =con.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader is=new InputStreamReader(in);
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(is);
            String read=br.readLine();
            String line;
              while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
               System.out.println(read);
               read+=line;
             }
```

Comment: hmm..but your code looks ok.Check this url in your computer browser that is it working or not?.Sometime Unknown Host exceptioncame because Host is not responding to your request.So try to clean project

Comment: i checked it with the browser and also writing this as a simple java application and it works fine.. but with android it shows this exception

Comment: I think you have problem with url as my code is running for my url.Once put http://www.google.com in my code.It will work fine

Comment: String newUrl = "http://www.exchangerate-api.com/"+from+"/"+to+"/"+amt+"?k=ZTKOy-28yPI-g2cQd"; i used it like this

Comment: if i just give **String newURL="google.com"** it throws malformedUrlException